# Add product to cart from main store product view page to second store cart

Tags: multistore, addtocart

I have setup *subdomain multi store*. The main store is on `domain.com` and another store view is at `store.domain.com`.

The main store holds all products. so I want customer to be able to add some of the products to cart from main store to `store.domain.com` cart.

I did tried url method like `store.domain.com/checkout/cart/add?product=[id]&qty=[qty]` as mentioned in [*Magento Wiki Page*](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/adding_a_product_to_the_cart_via_querystring),  but it is not working.

I believe the reason behind is, Magento recently implemented the feature *form key*.

Is there any other way to accomplish my requirement?

Comment: What is your purpose in doing this? Why not just do checkout in your main store if someone buys there?

Comment: @ToonVanDooren most of the products are can be added as quote request but some of the product can be purchased directly so I have dedicated one store for sales and another store for quotation. As I wanted to have both stores products in main domain can should be able add as quotation and sales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the session remains the same, you could add:

```
/form_key/<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()
```

You could make your session work at domain level by setting it in system configuration under system->configuration->web->session cookie management.

Comment: worked very well